# Airflow - How to perform callbacks on a DAG level

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a usecase in Airflow where I need to override the DAG class to create my own type of DAGs. What i require is, whenever my DAG is called i need to execute a certain function. I know there is `on_success_callback` and `on_failure_callback` but those are for individual tasks. What i require is a callback on a DAG level. That is on successful instantiation of the DAG, I require this function to be executed regardless of tasks states. How can i do this in Airflow 2.2.

Comment: I dont think this is possible. airflow execute the tasks so these are what running on the workers

Comment: From the docs: "on_failure_callback: A function to be called when a DagRun of this dag fails. A context dictionary is passed as a single parameter to this function." So it looks like the callbacks get called on a DAG level.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PythonOperator task that is the terminal task of the dag, with a trigger_rule of all_done.  Then implement your logic in a callable function and it will run when the dag finishes.

The task_id can be anything like "done" or whatever suits your requirements.